# Solar charger for MacBook Air 2015?

Tags: macbook-pro

Photographer needing Solar Charger for MacBook Air 2015 13in
What's available?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different. It would help us if you provided additional info, such as the types of OS, etc.  Also let us know what you've already done to solve the problem yourself.  Please see [ask] for how to ask good questions that have a better chance at being answered.

Comment: Looks more like a shopping question to me. Shopping questions are most likely off-topic here.

Answer (score 1):

You could contact [Voltaic Systems](https://www.voltaicsystems.com/).

I'm aware of users who have used these while on trekking holidays, so I'm sure you'll find they have a solution that works for you.

**Disclaimer:** I am not affiliated with Voltaic Systems in any way.